# SOLR Union of two queries

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

**I need union similar like sql below.**

Select top 10 * from table1 order by name desc
union 
Select top 5 * from table1 order by name asc

So the result should be a single list with 15 records.
Is it possible to do this in single query in SOLR ?

I am using SOLR 5.3.1

Thanks and really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Share your first query then I can try with the next one. Most probably we have to use  group.query

Comment: http://......?q=(*:*  *:*)&rows=10&fq=_indexname:(sample_index)&sort=_name desc or _query_:{rows=5&fq=_indexname:(sample_index)&sort=_name asc}. I am trying to achieve using that query but doesn't get the correct result

Comment: Try this, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping

Comment: I really don't have any idea how to achieve union through grouping. Any real example can you send me? Another thing is, do you know if SOLR natively supports union or not? Thanks and really appreciate your feedback